# Flex: change the application windows size

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am embedding the swf into a c# winform, now what I want to do is when I click a button inside the swf, the swf's size is changed. I have tried to use the stage class but failed, the system said the width/height property is not implemented:

```
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.width = 100;
            stage.height = 100;

            stage.invalidate();
        }
```

Is there any official way to change the application's size using code inside that application?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Application.application.width  = 100;
Application.application.height = 100;
```

Read more about this class on: [Adobe LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Application.html#application)